# How does std::unordered_map differentiate between values in the same bucket?

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashmap, unordered-map

I know that `std::unordered_map` handles key hash collisions by chaining keys with the same hash in a bucket (I think using a linked list). The question I have is how does it know which value, in the same bucket, corresponds to which key?

The naive idea I have is that each value is stored in a `std::pair`, is this how it is done?

Comment: Once a bucket is selected, it must do direct comparisons of the keys themselves to find the correct key. To learn more about how hash-tables work I suggest you implement one yourself. A hash-table, while not directly simple, is still rather trivial if you know about arrays and linked lists.

Comment: @wohlstad yeah you're right I edited it to remove that statement. I just thought there was something else done to only store the values in the map and not need to store the keys.

Comment: One option for implementation is to keep a vector of key+value pairs for each hash bucket. AFAIK the standard does not demand a specific implementation though.

Comment: @wohlstad: there are lots of constraints though... vector (by which I can only assume you mean something `std::vector`-like with contiguous memory) can not practically be used, because if collisions at that hash bucket mount up, the vector would need to resize and that involves moving the elements in memory - resizing in a hash table is not allowed to invalidate references to the existing elements (only iterators are invalidated).  (GCC actually has a singly-linked list of all elements; hash buckets contain iterators to the element before that bucket's first entry, so can rewire during erase).

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks for the clarification. I just meant some sort of a sequence of pairs and vector is the default sequence container that comes into mind. I admit I haven't thought of iterators invalidations, and guess a linked list is a better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's basically how it's done. Keep in mind that the key is *part of the data*. One of the things you can do with a map is iterate through its key/value pairs. This would be impossible, even with [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function), if the key itself were not stored.